# Can Non Struts tags be used in View component when going for struts2 framework.?

Tags: struts

Am New to struts2 framework . I wrote a small application and made it working . But our client is ver specific to its look feel and client side validations planning to use Jquery for front end layer .

Wanted to know can I achieve or write the non struts Tags in the JSP that am using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struts2 offers a great choice for server-side validation, through Java, XML or Annotations...

by the way, if you really want to perform only client side validation,

then yes,

you can put in the JSP the same javascript libraries that you would use in any non-struts JSP or HTML either...

just import them and start using them.

Comment: Okay thanks, ya I can use Javascripts for client side validations . But I have a Question. Is it possible to integrate with Jquery becasue for custom animations and Ajax calls I was planning to use jQuery.?

Comment: You can integrate any kind of AJAX technology you want in a Struts2 web application, with no limitation on number. Struts 2.0 integrates DOJO, since Struts 2.1 it is deprecated, and it is recommended JQuery, there is a Struts2 plugin for JQuery too... AJAX is just a methodology, even if the framework you are using propose something 'out of the box' you can always chose what you like. Hope that helps

Comment: oh good . I got confused as Struts has its own Ajax framework right.??

Comment: Ok thanks a lot . I was in dilemma on that . Now Quite clear. I will try to use the strust2 plugin for Jquery and will go ahead .

Comment: You're welcome. If you need examples on how to use jQuery to perform AJAX operations on Struts2, i suggest you to open a new question